# build a docker image for jupyter notebook in windows

Tags: windows, docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image in windows my docker file is:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

MAINTAINER Jon Krohn <jon@untapt.com>

USER $NB_USER

# install TensorFlow
RUN conda install --quiet --yes 'tensorflow=1.0*'

# install tflearn and keras: 
RUN pip install tflearn==0.3.2
RUN pip install keras==2.0.8

# install NLP packages:
RUN pip install nltk==3.2.4
RUN pip install gensim==2.3.0

# install Reinforcement Learning packages:
RUN pip install gym==0.9.4
```

but when I build it with this command

```
docker build -t tensorflow-ll-stack .
```

I get this error message

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::seaborn==0.9.0=py_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::matplotlib==3.0.3=py37_1
failed

SpecsConfigurationConflictError: Requested specs conflict with configured specs.
  requested specs:
    - tensorflow=1.0
  pinned specs:
    - python=3.7
Use 'conda config --show-sources' to look for 'pinned_specs' and 'track_features'
configuration parameters.  Pinned specs may also be defined in the file
/opt/conda/conda-meta/pinned.


The command '/bin/sh -c conda install --quiet --yes 'tensorflow=1.0*'' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar trouble setting up a docker image on Windows. For me it was an SSL certificate error and executing the following code prior to installing worked.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

So for your situation you could try this:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

MAINTAINER Jon Krohn <jon@untapt.com>

USER $NB_USER

# install TensorFlow
RUN conda config --set ssl_verify no
RUN conda install --quiet --yes 'tensorflow=1.0*'

# install tflearn and keras: 
RUN pip install tflearn==0.3.2
RUN pip install keras==2.0.8

# install NLP packages:
RUN pip install nltk==3.2.4
RUN pip install gensim==2.3.0

# install Reinforcement Learning packages:
RUN pip install gym==0.9.4
```